# Как в Windows 10 ассоциировать программу с расширениями?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

Есть программа program.exe. Её нужно связать с расширением txt.

Средствами C#.

Comment: `HKCR\txtfile\shell\open\command\@ = "(полное имя программы, с диском и путём)" %1`

Comment: как это использовать?

Comment: Пошарить по справке, как из шарпа работать с реестром. Найти. И, собсно, внести указанные изменения.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `FTYPE` командной строки. Она поможет сопоставить тип файла и приложение.

```
FTYPE типФайлов=команднаяСтрокаОткрытия
```

Тип файла для `.txt` обычно `txtfile`, но чтобы убедиться можно выполнить

```
ASSOC | find ".txt"
```

Далее выполняете команду от имени администратора, например,

```
FTYPE txtfile="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1
```

Comment: Как выполнить эту команду из C# с правами администратора, можно прочитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807429/running-cmd-commands-with-administrator-rights), либо задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Не работает `C:\Windows\system32>cmd.exe FTYPE txtfile="C:\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" txtfile
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2017. Все права защищены.

C:\Windows\system32>`

Comment: А если эта программа не была установлена то не будет работать?

Comment: @codename0082016 если запускаете из командной строки, то `cmd.exe` не нужно писать. Программа не должна быть установлена, программа должна находиться по пути `"C:\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" `

Comment: `FTYPE txtfile="C:\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" txtfile` после этого появляется меню `Каким образом вы хотите открыть этот файл?` Но в списке предложенных программ нету notepad++

Comment: @codename0082016 `FTYPE txtfile="C:\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1`, в каталоге `C:\Notepad++` должен находится файл `notepad++.exe`