# Как в Windows 10 изменить программу по умолчанию через cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

Как изменить программу по умолчанию через cmd?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670581

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня расширение pyw а не txt, ftype его не видит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Командой [`ASSOC`](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/assoc.html) ассоциируем расширение файла с типом файла

```
ASSOC .pyw=pywfile
```

Командой [`FTYPE`](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/ftype.html) сопоставляем тип файла и командную строку его открытия

```
FTYPE pywfile="C:\путь_до_программы\название_программы.exe" %1
```

Answer (score 0):

Cоздал я левое расширение, накинул на него программу и начал копаться в реестре. В итоге нашел это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создав уже вручную в реестре новое расширение и создав файл, файл открывается через программу указанную в реестре. Далее уже через команду REG в cmd можно назначить программу по умолчанию.