# Как изменить программу по умолчанию для .bat файлов в Windows 10?

Tags: bat

Я для консоли использую [вот это](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-us&gl=us) (Windows Terminal) приложение, соответственно хочу им открывать batники. Задался этим вопросом на stackoverflow, нашёл [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703970/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-windows-10-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-cmd?newreg=f0811be666f548159bc446dd5c8a737f) ссылку, если ввожу, получаю это:

```
C:\Users\Tima>ASSOC .bat=batfile
Access is denied.
Error occurred while processing: .bat.
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а если так - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44879643/9363441 ?

Comment: запустите cmd от имени администратора и там уже ASSOC FTYPE